# NHibernate Linq .Contains code generation has bug?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to achieve:

```
select StoreId, StoreName from Store where StoreId in (
     select StoreId from Employee where EmployeeName = 'Steve Jobs')
```

I have this code:

```
public class Store
{
  public virtual int StoreId { get; private set; }
  public virtual string StoreName { get; set; }

  public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
  public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

  public virtual int EmployeeId { get; private set; }
  public virtual string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}



var q = from s in session.Query<Store>()
        where 
            (from e in session.Query<Employee>()
            where s.EmployeeName == "Steve Jobs"
            select e.Store.StoreId).Contains(s.StoreId)
        select s;
```

NHibernate generates this (aliases stripped):

```
    select s.StoreId, s.StoreName
    from Store s
    where exists
        (
            select t.StoreId
            from Employee e
            left join Store t on t.StoreId = e.StoreId
            where e.EmployeeName = 'Steve Jobs'

                -- wrongly generated code
                and t.EmployeeId = s.StoreId 

        )
```

Linq-toSql generates the code correctly:

```
    select s.StoreId, s.StoreName
    from Store s
    where exists
        (
            select null
            from Employee e
            where e.EmployeeName = 'Steve Jobs'                        
                and e.StoreId = s.StoreId 

        )
```

Is there a problem with subquery code generation on Linq to NHibernate?

However, HQL works:

```
var q = session.CreateQuery("from Store as s where s.StoreId in (select e.WorkingInStore.StoreId from Employee as e where e.EmployeeName = 'lennon')").List<Store>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly looks like a bug, but I think you're overcomplicating the whole query. As I understand, you want all stores where an employee named Steve Jobs is on the payroll. Try:

```
var q = from s in session.Query<Store>()
        where s.Staff.Any(e=>e.EmployeeName == "Steve Jobs")
```

This should generate the query you want, and it's much cleaner and more readable than the subquery.

Comment: Cool, I should have thought of that, I've used **ANY** in SQL before,  or maybe I'm attempting it too much in a very Linq-y approach first and inspired by this http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql, avoiding lambda and extension methods if at all possible.  But on this case, **.Any** looks more elegant than pure Linq approach, and not all SQL concept can be captured in Linq syntax, extension method is warranted, **.Distinct()** comes to mind, http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/12/performing-order-by-on-distinct-on-linq.html

Comment: However, I hope Linq NHibernate team will fix the bug. Linq chaining is not only neat, it promotes code reuse too http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question in this post.  Instead of using Contains() operator, we can tweak the subquery a little bit and use Any() operator instead.

[LINQ to NHibernate WHERE EXISTS IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497802/linq-to-nhibernate-where-exists-in/9254927#9254927)