# LINQ to NHibernate WHERE EXISTS IN

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've been trying out NHibernate 3 and LINQ to NHibernate. I can't get it to spit out the correct T-SQL query.

Here's my domain model:

```
Employee { id, name }
Department { id, name }
EmployeeDepartment { id, employee_id, department_id, startdate, enddate }
AttendanceRegistration { id, datetime, employee_id }
```

Now suppose I'd like to select all AttendanceRegistrations between '2010-10-1' and '2010-11-1' that were connected to a certain department at that time.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010,10,1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2010,11,1);
var list = 
    from ar in session.Query<AttendanceRegistration>()
    where 
        start <= ar.datetime && ar.datetime > end && (
            from ed in session.Query<EmployeeDepartment>()
            where
                ed.startdate <= ar.datetime && ed.enddate > ar.datetime &&
                ed.department_id = 1
            select ed.employee_id
    ).Contains(ar.employee_id)
    select ar;
```

The resulting SQL Code will look like this:

```
select ar.id, ar.datetime, ar.employee_id
from AttendanceRegistration ar
where 
    '2010-10-1 00:00:00' <= ar.datetime and '2010-11-1' > ar.datetime and exists (
    select ed.employee_id
    from EmployeeDepartment ed
    where
        ed.department_id=1 and
        ed.startdate <= ar.datetime and
        ed.enddate > ar.datetime and
        ed.id=ar.employee_id
)
```

This is ALMOST good :-) The only mistake is

```
ed.id=ar.employee_id
```

This should have been:

```
ed.employee_id=ar.employee_id
```

Does anybody have ideas how to get LINQ to NHibernate spit out the correct T-SQL query?

Comment: Is this issue already resolved because if have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.  I found a way to get around this. Your query can be rewritten as follows. Basically instead of using Contains() operator, add your predicate explicitly in the where clause and use Any() operator.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010,10,1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2010,11,1);
var list = 
from ar in session.Query<AttendanceRegistration>()
where 
    start <= ar.datetime && ar.datetime > end && (
        from ed in session.Query<EmployeeDepartment>()
        where
            ed.startdate <= ar.datetime && ed.enddate > ar.datetime &&
            ed.department_id == 1
            && ed.employee_id == ar.employee_id
        select ed
    ).Any()
select ar;
```